# Django не находит файл в директории

Tags: python, django, path

имеется такая структура приложения:

```
App-|
    |-Utils-|
    |       |-Papka|
    |              |-File_func.py
    |              |-File_read.py
    |-views.py
```

Файл "File_func" имеет функцию "start", которая читает файл "File_func.py" в своей логике

```
with open('File_read.py', 'r') as file:
   ...
```

Проблема в том что, когда я вызываю функцию "start" из файла "File_func" в файле "views.py" он выдает ошибку, что не найден файл "File_read" в директории, но если я просто запущу эту функцию в файле "File_func", то она нормально отработает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397720/how-to-call-def-from-another-py-in-different-folder

Comment: И конечно документация https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предполагаю, что проблема может быть связана с тем, что путь, который указан в функции open, относительно неверен при вызове из файла views.py. В данном случае, файл File_read.py находится в папке Papka, а не в текущей директории, когда функция start вызывается из файла File_func.py.

попробуйте указать полный путь до файла File_read.py в функции open или использовать относительный путь, который учитывает текущую директорию при вызове из файла views.py.

примерно так:

```
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'Papka', 'File_read.py')

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
   ...
```

надеюсь поможет)